# Single query based on count result set in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @CreatedBy VARCHAR(100)='ABC',
      @CreatedDate DATETIME=GETDATE(),
      @ErrID INT

SELECT
    @Count = COUNT (1)
FROM TABLE1
WHERE CatName not in('XXX') and
ED IS NULL OR LTRIM(RTRIM(ED)) = ''

IF @Count >0

BEGIN 

SELECT @ErrID=ErrorID 
FROM    ErrorMessages
WHERE   Message LIKE 'ED is a mandatory field and cannot be left blank'

INSERT INTO ErrorLog 
            (
            
             CatName
            ,RowID
            ,ErrorID
            ,CreatedBy
            ,CreatedDate) 
                            
            SELECT
             CatName
            ,RowID
            , @ErrID
            , @CreatedBy
            , @CreatedDate
            FROM    TABLE1
            WHERE CatName not in('XXX') and
            ED IS NULL OR LTRIM(RTRIM(ED)) = ''

END
```

If you see above , Select is being ran twice if count>0 ,I am running the same select again..

I have some hundreds of validations to be done.. Is there any alternative way to avoid same query running again . (One to check count,if count >o,same select with additional columns insert into another table).

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: SQL SERVER 2019

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to *count* anything since you only want to know if *any* rows exist... so check exactly that. Also your *where* criteria looks suspect, you should probably be using parenthesis:

```
if exists (
  select * from table1
  where CatName not in('XXX') 
  and (ED is null or LTrim(RTrim(ED)) = '')
)
begin
...
```

However a better pattern would br to simply perform the insert and check the `@@rowcount`, then there's no need to repeat any query.

```
INSERT INTO ErrorLog...
SELECT...

if @@rowcount > 0 /* rows were inserted */
begin
  SELECT @ErrID = ErrorID
  ...
end
```

Comment: Even in above two cases too I need to write again select query to get rowId, catname from table1 inorder to insert into Errorlog..